# Locale as prefix and global for the whole site

Tags: symfony, yaml

I'm trying to define the routes of my site with `{_locale}` as a prefix so there will be routes like:

- mysite.com/about-us
- mysite.com/es/about-us
- mysite.com/en/about-us

My first problem is that defining `{_locale}` as prefix makes it mandatory and the route mysite.com/about-us won't work. Currently defined this way:

```
#Acme/WebBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
app_about_us:
    path: /{_locale}/about-us
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeWebBundle:Static:aboutUs, _locale: es}
    requirements:
    _locale:  es|en

#app/config/routing.yml
Acme_web:
    resource: "@AcmeWebBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Also, I don't want my routes to display the `{_locale}`, so that if anyone types:

- mysite.com/es/about-us it changes to *mysite.com

Finally if there is any way to set the prefix globally for all the site instead of putting it on every route would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all you can set [default locale](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#setting-a-default-locale) for a whole application

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    default_locale: en
```

Second - doing it this way, you can declare two routes:

```
app_about_us:
    path: /{_locale}/about-us
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeWebBundle:Static:aboutUs}
    requirements:
    _locale:  es|en

app_about_us_locale:
    path: /about-us
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeWebBundle:Static:aboutUs, _locale: es}
```

Im not sure is it possible to do it different way without additional bundles, events etc...

**Other way**

You can set session locale - [here is example to make locale sticky](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html).
This way you can create normal routing, without params. So how set new session locale? Create special routing to setting new locale and redirect to your original page.

```
app_set_locale:
    path: /{_locale}/
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeWebBundle:Locale:setLocale}
```

- inside controller set `locale` and **redirect** to previous page

Read Symfony documentation about Routing, Locale, Translate - maybe you will found something interesting :)